# Conversion of Hypergeometric functions from Maple to Mathematica

Tags: special-functions, maple, mathematica

After a calculation I found in Maple an expression of the kind:
$$f(x)=hypergeom\left(\left[\dfrac{a}{b},1\right],\left[c,d\right],h\right)$$
What is the equivalent notation in Mathematica which I suppose is the standard notation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica, it seems the syntax would be,

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{a/b,1},{c,d},h]
```

Checking how Maple translates that,

```
mmainput := `HypergeometricPFQ[{a/b,1},{c,d},h]`:

MmaTranslator:-FromMma(mmainput);

                    hypergeom([a/b, 1], [c, d], h)
```

Passing `HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4,1},{2,3},1.1]` to [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B3%2F4%2C1%7D%2C%7B2%2C3%7D%2C1.1%5D) agrees with Maple evaluating `hypergeom([3/4,1],[2,3],1.1)` as `1.163416426`.